# stalling Ubuntu 18.04.6

Tags: boot, 18.04, init

I'm trying to install Ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server-amd64 on a virtual machine via Hyper-v & it's not installing. Gives me the error

"/init: line 7:can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found"

But when I install version 20.04.3 it installs without any errors.
What can the problem be?

Comment: Did you verify the ISO?  If it can't find the installation media; that's usually an indication of an invalid ISO being detected.  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: Why do you want the older version 18.04.x when the newer version 20.04.x works? Both are LTS versions. For 18.04.x you can also try the old server iso file with the debian installer. You might have to update & upgrade more, but the result should be a good server. See [this link](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/bionic/daily/current/)

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, you either have to go to gen 1 as the Collutio indicates, or get 18.04.5 (for some reason, 18.04.6 will give you that bug in gen 2)

Answer (score 1):

I needed an old Ubuntu (downloaded ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso) to test some stuff and ended up with this same issue. What worked for me was while I was getting the repeated message `/init: line 7:can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found` during the initial boot, I quickly went to the settings of the VM (*File* -> *Settings* -> *DVD Driv*e) and inserted the .iso again. The process stopped for a second and then started loading the install. Now I am in the middle of an installation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I can only get 18.04 LTS to run on a generation 1 VM.  If I try generation 2 I get the exact error you're seeing.  No other changes to settings that I tried would fix the issue.

To those wondering why not just use 20.04 LTS, there are a few good reasons.  In my case I simply want to use Mail In A Box without hassle and they only update for every second LTS release.